# Documented process for using facebook connect for the iPhone to upload photos

Tags: iphone, facebook

After looking I did come accross this post on the facebook forums:

[link](http://forum.developers.facebook.com/viewtopic.php?id=30467)

They are feeding the facebook object a UIImage.  That seems logical, but where is this documented?  The API documentation is generalized to all platforms.  Where are the iPhone specific requirements for arguments and their data types?

Thanks

******Update*****
I still have not came across any API docs pertaining to Cocoa. I did, however, gather the information I needed by piecing together forum information, Facebook sample code, and some glue.

Hopefully they'll issue something a little more concrete over the next few months.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For completeness:

The following explains how to interact with Facebook Connect:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/

The API calls:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

If you need extended Permissions:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/policy/examples_and_explanations/Extended_Permissions/

A nice Obj-C wrapper on Mobile Orchard:
http://www.mobileorchard.com/marketing-in-code-part-2-setting-a-users-status-in-facebook-from-an-iphone-app-a-tutorial/

What follows is my implementation of a SessionViewController:

```
#import "SessionViewController.h"
#import "FBConnect.h"
#import "FBFeedDialog.h"

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// This application will not work until you enter your Facebook application's API key here:

static NSString* kApiKey = @"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

// Enter either your API secret or a callback URL (as described in documentation):
static NSString* kApiSecret = @"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"; // @"<YOUR SECRET KEY>";

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

@implementation SessionViewController

@synthesize label = _label;
@synthesize anImage;

- (void)done:(id)sender{

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];


}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// NSObject

- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _session = [[FBSession sessionForApplication:kApiKey secret:kApiSecret delegate:self] retain];
    }
    return self;
}


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
  if (self = [super initWithNibName:@"SessionViewController" bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {
      _session = [[FBSession sessionForApplication:kApiKey secret:kApiSecret delegate:self] retain];

  }
  return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [_session release];
    [anImage release];
    [super dealloc];
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// UIViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [_session resume];
  _loginButton.style = FBLoginButtonStyleWide;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
  return NO;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// FBDialogDelegate

- (void)dialog:(FBDialog*)dialog didFailWithError:(NSError*)error {
  _label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error(%d) %@", error.code,
    error.localizedDescription];
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// FBSessionDelegate

- (void)session:(FBSession*)session didLogin:(FBUID)uid {
  _permissionButton.hidden = NO;
  _feedButton.hidden = NO;

  NSString* fql = [NSString stringWithFormat:
    @"select uid,name from user where uid == %lld", session.uid];

  NSDictionary* params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:fql forKey:@"query"];
  [[FBRequest requestWithDelegate:self] call:@"facebook.fql.query" params:params];
}

- (void)sessionDidLogout:(FBSession*)session {
  _label.text = @"";
  _permissionButton.hidden = YES;
  _feedButton.hidden = YES;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// FBRequestDelegate

- (void)request:(FBRequest*)request didLoad:(id)result {

    if([result isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]){
        NSArray* users = result;
        NSDictionary* user = [users objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString* name = [user objectForKey:@"name"];
        _label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Logged in as %@", name];
    }  

}

- (void)request:(FBRequest*)request didFailWithError:(NSError*)error {
  _label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error(%d) %@", error.code,
    error.localizedDescription];
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

- (IBAction)askPermissionForPhotoUpload:(id)target {
    FBPermissionDialog* dialog = [[[FBPermissionDialog alloc] init] autorelease];
    dialog.delegate = self;
    dialog.permission = @"photo_upload";
    [dialog show];
}
- (IBAction)publishPhoto:(id)target{

    NSMutableDictionary *args = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
    [args setObject:self.anImage forKey:@"image"];  
    FBRequest *uploadPhotoRequest = [FBRequest requestWithDelegate:self];
    [uploadPhotoRequest call:@"photos.upload" params:args];
}


- (void)askPermission:(id)target {
  FBPermissionDialog* dialog = [[[FBPermissionDialog alloc] init] autorelease];
  dialog.delegate = self;
  dialog.permission = @"status_update";
  [dialog show];
}

- (void)publishFeed:(id)target {
  FBFeedDialog* dialog = [[[FBFeedDialog alloc] init] autorelease];
  dialog.delegate = self;
  dialog.templateBundleId = 9999999;
  dialog.templateData = @"{\"key1\": \"value1\"}";
  [dialog show];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Graph Api documentation of Photo upload are follows..

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/

And you can see how to do this in iPhone here.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1626/how-to-post-to-a-users-wall-upload-photos-and-add-a-like-button-from-your-iphone-app

Answer (score -2):

Joe Hewitt (the author of the Facebook iPhone app) released large parts of the Facebook application as his Three20 framework. It is hosted on [github](http://github.com/joehewitt/three20/tree/master).

Comment: I have seen that, but I am talking specifically about the iPhone Facebook Connect libraries.  These isn't any documentation regarding what data types to provide to the methods.