# FBConnect iPhone: uploading a photo album

Tags: iphone, upload, facebook

Can anyone provide an explanation of how I would go about uploading several photos to Facebook from my iPhone application using FBConnect? I've been reading the documentation, and I'm sort of stumped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750328/documented-process-for-using-facebook-connect-for-the-iphone-to-upload-photos) here on stackoverflow is a fine source of information :)

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the aid in the API request to the Album ID in question. To get the FB photo album id (assuming you already have a photo album), just navigate to the album and check the URL. You will see aid=[album id].