# how to uload photo/image to facebook via iphone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook

i am integrating facebook with my iphone application. i can share
text message in facebook, but i want to share/ upload
photos to facebook through my iphone application.
please let me know is there soution for this.
i am trying the facebook sample code but it is giving me some
errors: i searched out that error but other developer also 
facing this type of error. please let me know if there is 
some one who did upload/ share a photo on facebook in iphone
application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Documented process for using facebook connect for the iPhone to upload photos](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750328/documented-process-for-using-facebook-connect-for-the-iphone-to-upload-photos)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create an album for uploading images,after u have created an album via facebook api you have to use its id to upload photos

```
// for making a facebook album u have to make a multi-part form request
//to this url https://graph.facebook.com/100002232753228/albums
//where 100002232753228 is the fbid of the user and with form fields access_token,name,message, for reference go to -http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/

//To upload a foto to album send multi-part data to the url - https://graph.facebook.com/102657189818706/photos

//where 102657189818706 is the facebook id of the album created
```

Here is the code

```
#define kRequestBoundary @"----FOO"

    NSMutableData *postBody = [[NSMutableData alloc] init]; 
    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", kRequestBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; //starting the boundary of form data

                        [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"access_token\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; //setting field name of access_toke 
                        [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"200726069952695|fd9c7d8ed4b5592b1240cdb3-100002232753228|i7ae5By6VFItLliVT1jw5jsETEY"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    //setting field value of access_token

    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", kRequestBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; //closing the boundary for next field

    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"UserImage.png\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
//setting the field name of image

    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; //setting the content-Type of image



        UIImage *cropped=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Sample.png"];



    NSData *pImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(cropped);


    [postBody appendData:pImageData]; // adding image data to the request data

    [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",kRequestBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; //closing the 


    NSString *urlString = @"https://graph.facebook.com/102657189818706/photos";


    NSMutableURLRequest *request=[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:pUrl]];
    self.mURLrequest=request;
    [request release];
    [pUrl release];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", kRequestBoundary];

    [request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];
    [mURLrequest setHTTPBody:postBody];


    NSURLConnection *temp=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:mURLrequest delegate:self];
[temp autorelease];
```