# Publish picture to Facebook from my iphone app

Tags: iphone, facebook, publishing

Who can explain step by stem how to publish on the Facebook user account pictures and albums from my iPhone app?
I know about FB iPhone sdk, but cannot understand the whole process.
1. Should I register application on the FB?
2. Can I publish my local pics, or must use links on the previously published pics on hosts like yfrog.com.
3.etc

Comment: "the Facebook"...sounds like my parents. Lol 
did you try reading this? http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Facebook_iPhone_SDK

Comment: Yes, but did not found answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Documented process for using facebook connect for the iPhone to upload photos](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750328/documented-process-for-using-facebook-connect-for-the-iphone-to-upload-photos)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, implementing FB iPhone SDK for the first time is subject for a book...

Have you seen this video?

http://vimeo.com/3616452

It's a little outdated, but it was a good help for me to begin understanding the whole process...

As for question 2., I believe you can upload and publish the picture to FB user account, if you request the appropriate permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try ShareKit: http://www.getsharekit.com/

It makes things *real* easy :)