# adding photo on facebook wall

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

```
- (void)postToWall {
FBStreamDialog* dialog = [[[FBStreamDialog alloc] init] autorelease];

dialog.userMessagePrompt = [NSString stringWithFormat: subjectTitle]; //subjectTitle works here but not as name where i need it.

NSString *src = @"http://www.sample.com/image.png";
NSString *name = storyLink;  //<---------------------------------works with storyLink but not subjectTitle. I need subjectTitle to work here
NSString *href = storyLink;

NSString *attachment = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"name\":\"%@\",\"media\":[{\"type\":\"image\", \"src\":\"%@\", \"href\":\"%@\"}]}", name, src, href];
dialog.attachment = attachment;
[dialog show]; 
}
```

---

i want to add image from photo library instred of http://www.sample.com/image.png to the facebook wall.

can anyone provides me help ....

Thanks in advance ......

Comment: possible duplicate of [Documented process for using facebook connect for the iPhone to upload photos](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750328/documented-process-for-using-facebook-connect-for-the-iphone-to-upload-photos)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the URL's of the iPhoto library items using the UIImagePickerController and its delegate method.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

When the user picks a photo the URL will be in the dictionary under the key `UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL`

Comment: Hello in the dictionary info, the value for key UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL is NULL. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Hi have you pushed up the picker interface and picked an image from it? And you have set the delegate of the picker controller?

Comment: Were you able to get this to work?  I tried using the URL of a picture in NSTemporaryDirectory(), it doesn't show up... not sure if this is the same issue, I posted this at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137285/posting-picture-from-iphone-nstemporarydirectory-to-facebook-wall

Comment: Tried to get this to work with photo picker as described, couldn't get it to work... are you using facebook connect or the new graph API?

Answer (score 1):

Probably this [Stack Overflow Question about uploading images to Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750328/documented-process-for-using-facebook-connect-for-the-iphone-to-upload-photos) might help you.

Also Sharekit is a nice framework to add Social features to you iPhone App.  I think it has facility to share images. You can check it out at [Sharekit official website](http://getsharekit.com/).