# Posting picture from iphone to facebook wall

Tags: iphone, facebook, uiimage, nsurl

I'm using Facebook Connect for iOS to post a picture, taken in an app, to facebook wall, possible using the local file URL, according to another post:
[adding photo on facebook wall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793970/adding-photo-on-facebook-wall)

The URL appears to be pointing somewhere valid, but the picture doesn't show up.  Verified that it does work with a web link.  Anyone have an idea why this isn't working for local files?  Would I need permissions beyond regular wall posts?

Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to facebook, any image posted to a stream has to be web accessible, so what I wanted to do just isn't possible.  The only way to get this to work is to upload the picture somewhere first, then use that URL.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get URL it's better to use ALAssetsLibrary method: [writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:orientation:completionBlock:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/ALAssetsLibrary/writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum%3aorientation%3acompletionBlock%3a)

It returns the a saved image URL in its callback block: [ALAssetsLibraryWriteImageCompletionBlock](http://ALAssetsLibraryWriteImageCompletionBlock). Should note that it's only available from iOS 4.0