# Upload a UIImage from iPhone to Facebook

Tags: iphone, facebook, upload, uiimage

How do you upload a `UIImage`from iPhone to Facebook?

I'm using facebook-ios-sdk-8b3c17d version, and none of the other examples seem to be using the new facebook API.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here:

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk

in the example you can upload an image from your phone into your facebook photos.

Comment: sorry, but there is no such example there. could you post the code you were referring to?

Comment: @irad: if you download the code, is there a sinple method caled "postImage". Easy to use.

Comment: @irad: If you run sample code, in the first view you Can show a button action that permit you to Post an image on your profile. It's impossible to you that you don't see it.

Comment: 1. compiling the code and running it, providing a real appId, result in Facebook app on the iPhone being started, and that's all. the app itself goes back to the start and shows a login button only

Comment: 2. using this code- `NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 img, @"picture",
                                 nil];
  [_facebook requestWithMethodName:@"photos.upload"
                         andParams:params
                     andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                       andDelegate:self];
  [img release];
} results in this error message:`error_msg=Invalid API key, error_code=101}`

Comment: ah ok. You need to create an APP in facebook and set your returned API KEY in code. And it works! :)

Comment: I did create an app in Facebook... where do i set the API key?

Comment: @irad: in your sample proj probably in `viewDidLoad` find for a string named `apiKey` and paste your key (`apiKey = @"your key here";`).

Comment: sorry, but no string named apiKey in the sample. are you sure you are referring to the right sample code???

Comment: Yes.   you simply open all singles files and read all lines once you don't find key or somethink similar. I use this proj in ma y apps.

Comment: this is turning into an undesired chat that benefits no one, especially future readers. could you please post a complete code? thanks!

Comment: 1) Download code.  2) Navigate to "Sample/DemoApp/" and open file "DemoApp.xcodeproj". 3) In XCODE, select "DemoAppViewController.m". 4) At row n.25 substiture nil with @"YOURKEY". 5) Build and run

Comment: this is the appId that I set, not the appKey which is in the error message. they are not the same...

Answer (score 0):

this is the appId that I set, not the appKey which is in the error message. they are not the same...

Answer (score 0):

See my answer here

[Documented process for using facebook connect for the iPhone to upload photos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750328/documented-process-for-using-facebook-connect-for-the-iphone-to-upload-photos/6506549#6506549)

It using Graph Api for uploading photos.