# How to post a photos on facebook through iPhone app?

Tags: iphone

I am trying to post image on facebook but not successful yet,
my codes are:

```
- (void)postToWall{

int im = 1;
NSData *myimgData; 
myimgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:saveImagePath];
//pstimg = myimgData;
NSArray *chunks = [pstimg componentsSeparatedByString: @"."];
NSString *atch= [chunks objectAtIndex: 0];



NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:atch ofType:@"jpg"];  


img  = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

//start

FBDialog* dialog = [[[FBStreamDialog alloc] init] autorelease];

NSString *str = @"Hello"; 
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
dialog.cMessage=str;

dialog.userMessagePrompt = @"Enter your message:";


[dialog show];

NSData * findata;


    //edited from here


    if(im==1)
    {
        findata = myimgData;    

    }
    else
    {
        findata  = (NSData *)img;   

    }

    NSMutableDictionary * param = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   img, @"picture",
                                   nil];

    FBRequest *uploadPhotoRequest =[FBRequest requestWithDelegate:self] ;
    [uploadPhotoRequest call:@"facebook.photos.upload" params:param dataParam:myimgData];



    [img release];
```

}

But it not posted.

Comment: See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750328/documented-process-for-using-facebook-connect-for-the-iphone-to-upload-photos/6506549#6506549 It using Graph Api for uploading photos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To post a photo on Facebook you need to use the iOS SDK from Facebook:

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk

There you'll find sample app with authentication and much more, like posting a photo.

Comment: @Matteo: Thanks for quick response.I have done authentication part. and my text meassages are posted. I m also successful to import image data in myimageData.But i think this code not working:[uploadPhotoRequest call:@"facebook.photos.upload" params:param dataParam:myimgData];

Comment: did you get some callback from Facebook?

Comment: and at https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk, in this link, there is no sample to post image.

Comment: yes... there are no sample for posting photos. Maybe you can try to load on facebook an image from url (urlOfImage).

  NSDictionary* param = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              [NSArray arrayWithObject:media], @"media",
                              [urlOfImage absoluteString], @"href", nil];