# Post image on Facebook wall through iPhone app

Tags: iphone, facebook, image, post, share

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Documented process for using facebook connect for the iPhone to upload photos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750328/documented-process-for-using-facebook-connect-for-the-iphone-to-upload-photos)

I have aמ iPhone app and would like to know how to make an image which, when clicked, the image will be posted to the user's Facebook profile.

The app is based on Facebook, i mean, you register with your Facebook account.

Answer (score 0):

Use [facebook's sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk) to post photos, text and links. Or you may use [Sharekit](http://getsharekit.com/) - it's a powerful sdk to post on Facebook, Twitter, ReadItLater and others.

Comment: i think it will be an html landing page, so basically i need landing page with a photo, that when you click it it post it on your wall

Comment: just try one of above, you will see the use

Comment: i dont need code for ios, i need a code for a simple html landing page

Comment: I believe things that you call "simple" are not simple at all

Comment: my page is simple html code, with only <img> in it, i want to know how to make the image also a button, that when you click the image, it will post the image on your facebook wall